# Facebook: Post Video only for fans of my page?

Tags: facebook

I was wondering if I can post a video on my Facebook fanpage which can only be viewed by my fans.

Thanks,

Comment: This is related to programming how?

Comment: Case maybe I could publish the Video via Graph API and set extended permissions.

Comment: On your Facebook Fan Page **TAB** or just on your Facebook Page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can Do it.
Add the App name **"Static Html"** to your page.
There you have get two options,
one is fan only content and non-fan contents.

Post your video embed code in fan only content box.
So only your fan can view that video.